# How to get out of the building after collecting the money bags in "Death to a traitor" mission?

Tags: the-godfather

Have done this broad a 1000 times and can never make it out of the building in time when I collect the money bags after I set the bomb in the bar. If I skip getting the money bags I can make it.

I'm looking for some advice on what to do to collect money bags and still make it out in time.